# Smartdiagram is hyphenating too much

Tags: tikz-pgf, hyphenation, smartdiagram

I am trying to make a constellation style diagram but when I insert the words that I want to use, it is hyphenating too much. I don't have an issue that the diagram is wide. Essentially, I am trying to make:

[image]

and I'm using the following code to do it:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}

\begin{document}
\smartdiagramset{set color list={orange!60, green!50!lime!60,magenta!60,
blue!50!cyan},
uniform connection color=true
}
\smartdiagram[constellation diagram]{
Industry Rivalry,Suppliers,Substitutes,Buyers,Potential Entrants
}
\end{document}
```

and this is the result:

[image: Not so good version of porter's five]

Comment: Would you mind posting the code for the first example as well for my own benefit?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To avoid this problem you can play with the size of the *planet*s and *satellite*s via the `planet text width` and `satellite text width` options. By default they are set to `1.75cm` and `1.5cm` respectively and let them increase allows actually to set the `text width` of usual TikZ nodes.

I would propose the following thus:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}

\begin{document}
\smartdiagramset{set color list={orange!60, green!50!lime!60,magenta!60,
blue!50!cyan},
uniform connection color=true,
distance planet-satellite=4cm,
satellite text width=2cm,
planet text width=2.75cm,
}
\smartdiagram[constellation diagram]{
Industry Rivalry,Suppliers,Substitutes,Buyers,Potential Entrants
}
\end{document}
```

where the `distance planet-satellite` has been increased to make the diagram nicer.

The result:

[image]

In case of problems with the size, it is always possible to scale the diagram with `\scalebox`:

```
\scalebox{0.7}{
    \smartdiagram[constellation diagram]{
    Industry Rivalry,Suppliers,Substitutes,Buyers,Potential Entrants
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow! That's a neat solution! Thanks! I was wondering, if you don't mind, what would be the best way to have a caption on right rather than the bottom? EDIT: Figured it out! `:)`